# FFmpeg Sequentially Apply Filters

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm very new to FFmpeg (just installed it this morning) and need it to do a very specific task. I have a bunch of long recordings that I need to split into non-uniform sections, add some padding (videos are 4:3 but the title is 16:9), and add a title image to the beginning. Through looking around this site I've found out how to do all 3 of these things independently, but I was hoping to save some time and do it in a single command. Here's the code I've put together:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -i image.jpeg -ss 00:00:55 -to 1:00:00 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=0:0:enable='between(t,0,4)', pad=854:480:107:0" -pix_fmt yuv420p -q:v 3 output.wmv
```

However, there's no title screen when I play back the output. I feel like it's adding the overlay first, and then splitting the video, so the overlay gets removed. I've seen other questions asking about applying multiple filters, however they never seem to be order dependent.

Ultimately I'm just trying to complete these 3 actions as efficiently as possible.

EDIT: Since it was pointed out that I didn't, I'll explicitly ask a question:

**How do I execute splitting a video, then adding padding to the video, and finally add a title screen in a single FFmpeg command?**

EDIT 2: Output log was requested:

```
ffmpeg version 2.7.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --disable-doc --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, asf, from 'input.wmv':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: AP@L1
    WMFSDKVersion   : 12.0.7601.17514
    IsVBR           : 0
  Duration: 00:26:36.62, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1266 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, fltp, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: vc1 (Advanced) (WVC1 / 0x31435657), yuv420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 1000 kb/s, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none, 4 kb/s
Input #1, image2, from 'image.jpeg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 67719 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1650x927 [SAR 72:72 DAR 550:309], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[swscaler @ 0x7fbe52008c00] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] removing common factors from framerate
Output #0, asf, to 'output.wmv':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    DeviceConformanceTemplate: AP@L1
    WMFSDKVersion   : 12.0.7601.17514
    IsVBR           : 0
    WM/EncodingSettings: Lavf56.36.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4) (MP43 / 0x3334504D), yuv420p, 854x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 427:240], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 msmpeg4
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 wmav2
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (vc1) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
  pad (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (msmpeg4)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (wmav2 (native) -> wmav2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    8 fps=5.3 q=3.0 size=      64kB time=00:00:00.26 bitrate=1948.4kbits/sPast duration 0.609993 too large
    Last message repeated 1 times
Past duration 0.619987 too large
Past duration 0.609993 too large
Past duration 0.619987 too large
Past duration 0.609993 too large
...
Past duration 0.789986 too large
frame=  191 fps= 95 q=3.0 size=    1398kB time=00:00:06.36 bitrate=1798.6kbits/sPast duration 0.799995 too large
Past duration 0.809990 too large
...
Past duration 0.999992 too large
    Last message repeated 2 times
frame=  373 fps=149 q=3.0 size=    2814kB time=00:00:12.43 bitrate=1853.8kbits/sframe=  560 fps=186 q=3.0 size=    4223kB time=00:00:18.66 bitrate=1853.2kbits/sframe=  746 fps=213 q=3.0 size=    5717kB time=00:00:24.86 bitrate=1883.2kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame=  928 fps=232 q=3.0 size=    7501kB time=00:00:30.93 bitrate=1986.5kbits/sframe= 1121 fps=249 q=3.0 size=    8885kB time=00:00:37.36 bitrate=1947.9kbits/sframe= 1313 fps=262 q=3.0 size=   10235kB time=00:00:43.76 bitrate=1915.8kbits/sframe= 1506 fps=273 q=3.0 size=   11510kB time=00:00:50.20 bitrate=1878.3kbits/sframe= 1696 fps=282 q=3.0 size=   12892kB time=00:00:56.53 bitrate=1868.1kbits/sPast duration 0.899986 too large
frame= 1891 fps=290 q=3.0 size=   14189kB time=00:01:03.03 bitrate=1844.0kbits/sframe= 2081 fps=297 q=3.0 size=   15479kB time=00:01:09.36 bitrate=1828.0kbits/sframe= 2274 fps=302 q=3.0 size=   16851kB time=00:01:15.80 bitrate=1821.2kbits/sPast duration 0.929985 too large
frame= 2465 fps=307 q=3.0 size=   18089kB time=00:01:22.16 bitrate=1803.4kbits/sframe= 2650 fps=311 q=3.0 size=   19648kB time=00:01:28.33 bitrate=1822.1kbits/sframe= 2820 fps=312 q=3.0 size=   21167kB time=00:01:34.00 bitrate=1844.6kbits/sPast duration 0.939995 too large
frame= 2999 fps=315 q=3.0 size=   22504kB time=00:01:39.96 bitrate=1844.1kbits/sframe= 3175 fps=317 q=3.0 size=   24067kB time=00:01:45.83 bitrate=1862.9kbits/sframe= 3350 fps=318 q=3.0 size=   25779kB time=00:01:51.66 bitrate=1891.2kbits/sframe= 3521 fps=319 q=3.0 size=   27420kB time=00:01:57.36 bitrate=1913.8kbits/sPast duration 0.979988 too large
frame= 3697 fps=321 q=3.0 size=   29042kB time=00:02:03.23 bitrate=1930.6kbits/sframe= 3866 fps=321 q=3.0 size=   30767kB time=00:02:08.86 bitrate=1955.8kbits/sframe= 4036 fps=322 q=3.0 size=   32132kB time=00:02:14.53 bitrate=1956.6kbits/sframe= 4208 fps=323 q=3.0 size=   33767kB time=00:02:20.26 bitrate=1972.1kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame= 4383 fps=324 q=3.0 size=   35560kB time=00:02:26.10 bitrate=1993.9kbits/sframe= 4550 fps=324 q=3.0 size=   37348kB time=00:02:31.66 bitrate=2017.3kbits/sframe= 4734 fps=326 q=3.0 size=   38914kB time=00:02:37.80 bitrate=2020.1kbits/sframe= 4929 fps=328 q=3.0 size=   40160kB time=00:02:44.30 bitrate=2002.4kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame= 5127 fps=330 q=3.0 size=   41457kB time=00:02:50.90 bitrate=1987.2kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame= 5322 fps=332 q=3.0 size=   42895kB time=00:02:57.40 bitrate=1980.8kbits/sframe= 5518 fps=334 q=3.0 size=   44160kB time=00:03:03.93 bitrate=1966.8kbits/sframe= 5715 fps=335 q=3.0 size=   45623kB time=00:03:10.50 bitrate=1961.9kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame= 5904 fps=337 q=3.0 size=   46889kB time=00:03:16.80 bitrate=1951.8kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 3 times
frame= 6093 fps=338 q=3.0 size=   48235kB time=00:03:23.10 bitrate=1945.6kbits/sframe= 6289 fps=339 q=3.0 size=   49564kB time=00:03:29.63 bitrate=1936.8kbits/sPast duration 0.639992 too large
frame= 6479 fps=340 q=3.0 size=   50832kB time=00:03:35.96 bitrate=1928.2kbits/sframe= 6671 fps=341 q=3.0 size=   51960kB time=00:03:42.36 bitrate=1914.2kbits/sframe= 6870 fps=343 q=3.0 size=   53257kB time=00:03:49.00 bitrate=1905.2kbits/sframe= 7073 fps=344 q=3.0 size=   54610kB time=00:03:55.76 bitrate=1897.5kbits/sframe= 7279 fps=346 q=3.0 size=   55820kB time=00:04:02.63 bitrate=1884.6kbits/sframe= 7484 fps=347 q=3.0 size=   57126kB time=00:04:09.46 bitrate=1875.9kbits/sPast duration 0.709999 too large
frame= 7690 fps=349 q=3.0 size=   58432kB time=00:04:16.33 bitrate=1867.4kbits/sframe= 7887 fps=350 q=3.0 size=   59789kB time=00:04:22.90 bitrate=1863.0kbits/sframe= 8078 fps=350 q=3.0 size=   61210kB time=00:04:29.26 bitrate=1862.2kbits/sPast duration 0.719994 too large
frame= 8274 fps=351 q=3.0 size=   62635kB time=00:04:35.80 bitrate=1860.4kbits/sframe= 8473 fps=352 q=3.0 size=   63873kB time=00:04:42.43 bitrate=1852.6kbits/sframe= 8657 fps=352 q=3.0 size=   65129kB time=00:04:48.56 bitrate=1848.9kbits/sPast duration 0.749992 too large
frame= 8851 fps=353 q=3.0 size=   66367kB time=00:04:55.03 bitrate=1842.8kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame= 9046 fps=354 q=3.0 size=   67607kB time=00:05:01.53 bitrate=1836.7kbits/sframe= 9243 fps=355 q=3.0 size=   68857kB time=00:05:08.10 bitrate=1830.8kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame= 9439 fps=355 q=3.0 size=   70220kB time=00:05:14.63 bitrate=1828.3kbits/sPast duration 0.789986 too large
frame= 9633 fps=356 q=3.0 size=   71357kB time=00:05:21.10 bitrate=1820.5kbits/sframe= 9833 fps=357 q=3.0 size=   72601kB time=00:05:27.76 bitrate=1814.5kbits/sframe=10035 fps=358 q=3.0 size=   73892kB time=00:05:34.50 bitrate=1809.6kbits/sPast duration 0.809990 too large
frame=10241 fps=358 q=3.0 size=   75151kB time=00:05:41.36 bitrate=1803.4kbits/sframe=10440 fps=359 q=3.0 size=   76623kB time=00:05:48.00 bitrate=1803.7kbits/sframe=10648 fps=360 q=3.0 size=   78045kB time=00:05:54.93 bitrate=1801.3kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 2 times
frame=10847 fps=361 q=3.0 size=   79317kB time=00:06:01.56 bitrate=1797.1kbits/sframe=11040 fps=361 q=3.0 size=   80542kB time=00:06:08.00 bitrate=1792.9kbits/sframe=11241 fps=362 q=3.0 size=   81904kB time=00:06:14.70 bitrate=1790.7kbits/sPast duration 0.859993 too large
frame=11443 fps=362 q=3.0 size=   83151kB time=00:06:21.43 bitrate=1785.8kbits/sframe=11649 fps=363 q=3.0 size=   84745kB time=00:06:28.30 bitrate=1787.9kbits/sframe=11849 fps=364 q=3.0 size=   86079kB time=00:06:34.96 bitrate=1785.4kbits/sframe=12059 fps=365 q=3.0 size=   87401kB time=00:06:41.96 bitrate=1781.2kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame=12263 fps=365 q=3.0 size=   88876kB time=00:06:48.76 bitrate=1781.1kbits/sframe=12466 fps=366 q=3.0 size=   90226kB time=00:06:55.53 bitrate=1778.8kbits/sframe=12672 fps=366 q=3.0 size=   91529kB time=00:07:02.40 bitrate=1775.1kbits/sframe=12878 fps=367 q=3.0 size=   92795kB time=00:07:09.26 bitrate=1770.9kbits/sframe=13085 fps=368 q=3.0 size=   94123kB time=00:07:16.16 bitrate=1767.8kbits/sPast duration 0.969994 too large
frame=13293 fps=368 q=3.0 size=   95407kB time=00:07:23.10 bitrate=1763.9kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame=13500 fps=369 q=3.0 size=   96664kB time=00:07:30.00 bitrate=1759.7kbits/sframe=13707 fps=370 q=3.0 size=   97904kB time=00:07:36.90 bitrate=1755.4kbits/sframe=13914 fps=370 q=3.0 size=   99189kB time=00:07:43.80 bitrate=1751.9kbits/sframe=14120 fps=371 q=3.0 size=  100489kB time=00:07:50.66 bitrate=1749.0kbits/sframe=14321 fps=371 q=3.0 size=  101785kB time=00:07:57.36 bitrate=1746.7kbits/sframe=14523 fps=372 q=3.0 size=  103107kB time=00:08:04.10 bitrate=1744.8kbits/sframe=14721 fps=372 q=3.0 size=  104339kB time=00:08:10.70 bitrate=1741.9kbits/sframe=14925 fps=372 q=3.0 size=  105748kB time=00:08:17.50 bitrate=1741.3kbits/sframe=15126 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  107220kB time=00:08:24.20 bitrate=1742.1kbits/sframe=15337 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  108342kB time=00:08:31.23 bitrate=1736.1kbits/sframe=15539 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  109554kB time=00:08:37.96 bitrate=1732.7kbits/sframe=15743 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  110823kB time=00:08:44.76 bitrate=1730.0kbits/sframe=15949 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  112092kB time=00:08:51.63 bitrate=1727.2kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
Past duration 0.629997 too large
frame=16153 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  113489kB time=00:08:58.43 bitrate=1726.7kbits/sframe=16361 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  114714kB time=00:09:05.36 bitrate=1723.1kbits/sframe=16567 fps=376 q=3.0 size=  115951kB time=00:09:12.23 bitrate=1720.1kbits/sframe=16757 fps=376 q=3.0 size=  117579kB time=00:09:18.56 bitrate=1724.4kbits/sframe=16939 fps=376 q=3.0 size=  118901kB time=00:09:24.63 bitrate=1725.1kbits/sframe=17118 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  120689kB time=00:09:30.60 bitrate=1732.7kbits/sPast duration 0.649986 too large
frame=17303 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  122307kB time=00:09:36.76 bitrate=1737.2kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 30 times
frame=17478 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  123682kB time=00:09:42.60 bitrate=1739.1kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame=17657 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  125717kB time=00:09:48.56 bitrate=1749.8kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame=17834 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  127445kB time=00:09:54.46 bitrate=1756.2kbits/sframe=18009 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  129114kB time=00:10:00.30 bitrate=1761.9kbits/sframe=18187 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  130673kB time=00:10:06.23 bitrate=1765.8kbits/sframe=18360 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  132370kB time=00:10:12.00 bitrate=1771.9kbits/sPast duration 0.729988 too large
frame=18537 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  133892kB time=00:10:17.90 bitrate=1775.1kbits/sframe=18710 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  135757kB time=00:10:23.66 bitrate=1783.2kbits/sframe=18889 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  137323kB time=00:10:29.63 bitrate=1786.7kbits/sPast duration 0.779991 too large
frame=19065 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  139135kB time=00:10:35.50 bitrate=1793.5kbits/sframe=19241 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  140776kB time=00:10:41.36 bitrate=1798.1kbits/sframe=19414 fps=372 q=3.0 size=  142520kB time=00:10:47.13 bitrate=1804.1kbits/sframe=19583 fps=372 q=3.0 size=  144248kB time=00:10:52.76 bitrate=1810.3kbits/sframe=19765 fps=372 q=3.0 size=  145923kB time=00:10:58.83 bitrate=1814.4kbits/sframe=19933 fps=372 q=3.0 size=  148123kB time=00:11:04.43 bitrate=1826.3kbits/sframe=20104 fps=371 q=3.0 size=  149760kB time=00:11:10.13 bitrate=1830.7kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame=20273 fps=371 q=3.0 size=  151767kB time=00:11:15.76 bitrate=1839.8kbits/sframe=20452 fps=371 q=3.0 size=  153332kB time=00:11:21.73 bitrate=1842.5kbits/sframe=20639 fps=371 q=3.0 size=  154926kB time=00:11:27.96 bitrate=1844.8kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame=20832 fps=371 q=3.0 size=  156348kB time=00:11:34.40 bitrate=1844.5kbits/sframe=21027 fps=371 q=3.0 size=  157679kB time=00:11:40.90 bitrate=1842.9kbits/sframe=21217 fps=371 q=3.0 size=  158851kB time=00:11:47.23 bitrate=1840.0kbits/sframe=21401 fps=371 q=3.0 size=  160207kB time=00:11:53.36 bitrate=1839.8kbits/sPast duration 0.899986 too large
frame=21597 fps=371 q=3.0 size=  161420kB time=00:11:59.90 bitrate=1836.9kbits/sframe=21795 fps=372 q=3.0 size=  162817kB time=00:12:06.50 bitrate=1835.9kbits/sframe=21988 fps=372 q=3.0 size=  164139kB time=00:12:12.93 bitrate=1834.6kbits/sframe=22193 fps=372 q=3.0 size=  165404kB time=00:12:19.76 bitrate=1831.6kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame=22395 fps=372 q=3.0 size=  166648kB time=00:12:26.50 bitrate=1828.8kbits/sframe=22598 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  167923kB time=00:12:33.26 bitrate=1826.2kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame=22801 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  169426kB time=00:12:40.03 bitrate=1826.2kbits/sframe=23001 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  170732kB time=00:12:46.70 bitrate=1824.2kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame=23198 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  172217kB time=00:12:53.26 bitrate=1824.5kbits/sframe=23402 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  173517kB time=00:13:00.06 bitrate=1822.2kbits/sframe=23604 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  174810kB time=00:13:06.80 bitrate=1820.1kbits/sframe=23802 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  176326kB time=00:13:13.40 bitrate=1820.6kbits/sframe=23990 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  177517kB time=00:13:19.66 bitrate=1818.5kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 3 times
frame=24188 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  178867kB time=00:13:26.26 bitrate=1817.4kbits/sframe=24380 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  180214kB time=00:13:32.66 bitrate=1816.6kbits/sframe=24570 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  181485kB time=00:13:39.00 bitrate=1815.3kbits/sPast duration 0.769997 too large
frame=24758 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  182826kB time=00:13:45.26 bitrate=1814.8kbits/sframe=24949 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  184367kB time=00:13:51.63 bitrate=1816.1kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame=25137 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  185835kB time=00:13:57.90 bitrate=1816.9kbits/sframe=25327 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  187454kB time=00:14:04.23 bitrate=1819.0kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame=25512 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  188804kB time=00:14:10.40 bitrate=1818.8kbits/sframe=25699 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  190426kB time=00:14:16.63 bitrate=1821.0kbits/sframe=25880 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  191807kB time=00:14:22.66 bitrate=1821.4kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 2 times
frame=26058 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  193351kB time=00:14:28.60 bitrate=1823.5kbits/sframe=26246 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  194951kB time=00:14:34.86 bitrate=1825.5kbits/sframe=26437 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  196310kB time=00:14:41.23 bitrate=1824.9kbits/sPast duration 0.669991 too large
frame=26624 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  198126kB time=00:14:47.46 bitrate=1828.9kbits/sframe=26809 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  199676kB time=00:14:53.63 bitrate=1830.4kbits/sframe=26997 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  201229kB time=00:14:59.90 bitrate=1831.8kbits/sframe=27178 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  202660kB time=00:15:05.93 bitrate=1832.6kbits/sframe=27362 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  204179kB time=00:15:12.06 bitrate=1833.9kbits/sframe=27553 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  205745kB time=00:15:18.43 bitrate=1835.1kbits/sPast duration 0.679985 too large
frame=27734 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  207492kB time=00:15:24.46 bitrate=1838.7kbits/sframe=27915 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  209114kB time=00:15:30.50 bitrate=1841.0kbits/sframe=28092 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  210639kB time=00:15:36.40 bitrate=1842.7kbits/sframe=28272 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  212204kB time=00:15:42.40 bitrate=1844.6kbits/sframe=28452 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  213664kB time=00:15:48.40 bitrate=1845.6kbits/sframe=28633 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  215214kB time=00:15:54.43 bitrate=1847.2kbits/sframe=28818 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  216795kB time=00:16:00.60 bitrate=1848.8kbits/sframe=29008 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  218320kB time=00:16:06.93 bitrate=1849.6kbits/sframe=29193 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  219901kB time=00:16:13.10 bitrate=1851.2kbits/sframe=29375 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  221492kB time=00:16:19.16 bitrate=1853.1kbits/sframe=29551 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  222929kB time=00:16:25.03 bitrate=1854.0kbits/sframe=29726 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  224467kB time=00:16:30.86 bitrate=1855.8kbits/sframe=29910 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  226004kB time=00:16:37.00 bitrate=1857.0kbits/sframe=30075 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  227589kB time=00:16:42.50 bitrate=1859.8kbits/sframe=30257 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  229260kB time=00:16:48.56 bitrate=1862.1kbits/sframe=30446 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  230826kB time=00:16:54.86 bitrate=1863.2kbits/sframe=30634 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  232523kB time=00:17:01.13 bitrate=1865.4kbits/sPast duration 0.839989 too large
frame=30821 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  234085kB time=00:17:07.36 bitrate=1866.5kbits/sframe=31011 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  235601kB time=00:17:13.70 bitrate=1867.1kbits/sframe=31195 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  237201kB time=00:17:19.83 bitrate=1868.7kbits/sframe=31382 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  238814kB time=00:17:26.06 bitrate=1870.2kbits/sPast duration 0.879997 too large
frame=31570 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  240367kB time=00:17:32.33 bitrate=1871.2kbits/sframe=31754 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  241882kB time=00:17:38.46 bitrate=1872.0kbits/sframe=31942 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  243492kB time=00:17:44.73 bitrate=1873.4kbits/sframe=32132 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  245098kB time=00:17:51.06 bitrate=1874.6kbits/sframe=32316 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  246779kB time=00:17:57.20 bitrate=1876.7kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame=32484 fps=372 q=3.0 size=  248717kB time=00:18:02.80 bitrate=1881.7kbits/sPast duration 0.969994 too large
frame=32657 fps=372 q=3.0 size=  250532kB time=00:18:08.56 bitrate=1885.4kbits/sframe=32853 fps=372 q=3.0 size=  251945kB time=00:18:15.10 bitrate=1884.7kbits/sframe=33052 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  253229kB time=00:18:21.73 bitrate=1882.9kbits/sframe=33253 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  254451kB time=00:18:28.43 bitrate=1880.5kbits/sframe=33452 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  255732kB time=00:18:35.06 bitrate=1878.8kbits/sframe=33655 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  256998kB time=00:18:41.83 bitrate=1876.7kbits/sframe=33851 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  258354kB time=00:18:48.36 bitrate=1875.7kbits/sframe=34054 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  259692kB time=00:18:55.13 bitrate=1874.1kbits/sframe=34252 fps=373 q=3.0 size=  261089kB time=00:19:01.73 bitrate=1873.3kbits/sframe=34451 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  262389kB time=00:19:08.36 bitrate=1871.8kbits/sframe=34654 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  263689kB time=00:19:15.13 bitrate=1870.0kbits/sframe=34855 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  264904kB time=00:19:21.83 bitrate=1867.8kbits/sframe=35055 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  266151kB time=00:19:28.50 bitrate=1865.9kbits/sframe=35260 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  267485kB time=00:19:35.33 bitrate=1864.4kbits/sframe=35461 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  268895kB time=00:19:42.03 bitrate=1863.6kbits/sframe=35660 fps=374 q=3.0 size=  270035kB time=00:19:48.66 bitrate=1861.0kbits/sframe=35858 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  271201kB time=00:19:55.26 bitrate=1858.7kbits/sframe=36055 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  272454kB time=00:20:01.83 bitrate=1857.1kbits/sframe=36247 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  273657kB time=00:20:08.23 bitrate=1855.4kbits/sframe=36442 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  274939kB time=00:20:14.73 bitrate=1854.1kbits/sframe=36634 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  276164kB time=00:20:21.13 bitrate=1852.6kbits/sframe=36841 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  277489kB time=00:20:28.03 bitrate=1851.1kbits/sframe=37043 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  278717kB time=00:20:34.76 bitrate=1849.1kbits/sframe=37247 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  280001kB time=00:20:41.56 bitrate=1847.5kbits/sPast duration 0.679985 too large
frame=37444 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  281182kB time=00:20:48.13 bitrate=1845.5kbits/sframe=37644 fps=375 q=3.0 size=  282467kB time=00:20:54.80 bitrate=1844.1kbits/sframe=37836 fps=376 q=3.0 size=  283717kB time=00:21:01.20 bitrate=1842.9kbits/sframe=38040 fps=376 q=3.0 size=  285001kB time=00:21:08.00 bitrate=1841.3kbits/sframe=38246 fps=376 q=3.0 size=  286248kB time=00:21:14.86 bitrate=1839.4kbits/sframe=38440 fps=376 q=3.0 size=  287454kB time=00:21:21.33 bitrate=1837.8kbits/sPast duration 0.749992 too large
frame=38632 fps=376 q=3.0 size=  288860kB time=00:21:27.73 bitrate=1837.6kbits/sframe=38832 fps=376 q=3.0 size=  290151kB time=00:21:34.40 bitrate=1836.3kbits/sframe=39031 fps=376 q=3.0 size=  291545kB time=00:21:41.03 bitrate=1835.7kbits/sframe=39230 fps=376 q=3.0 size=  292751kB time=00:21:47.66 bitrate=1834.0kbits/sframe=39434 fps=376 q=3.0 size=  293960kB time=00:21:54.46 bitrate=1832.0kbits/sframe=39637 fps=377 q=3.0 size=  295314kB time=00:22:01.23 bitrate=1831.0kbits/sframe=39837 fps=377 q=3.0 size=  296742kB time=00:22:07.90 bitrate=1830.6kbits/sframe=40030 fps=377 q=3.0 size=  298304kB time=00:22:14.33 bitrate=1831.4kbits/sframe=40221 fps=377 q=3.0 size=  299939kB time=00:22:20.70 bitrate=1832.7kbits/sPast duration 0.849998 too large
frame=40412 fps=377 q=3.0 size=  301276kB time=00:22:27.06 bitrate=1832.2kbits/sframe=40611 fps=377 q=3.0 size=  302492kB time=00:22:33.70 bitrate=1830.5kbits/sframe=40813 fps=377 q=3.0 size=  303748kB time=00:22:40.43 bitrate=1829.1kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
    Last message repeated 3 times
Past duration 0.889992 too large
frame=41013 fps=377 q=3.0 size=  305282kB time=00:22:47.10 bitrate=1829.3kbits/sframe=41210 fps=377 q=3.0 size=  306785kB time=00:22:53.66 bitrate=1829.5kbits/sframe=41416 fps=377 q=3.0 size=  308217kB time=00:23:00.53 bitrate=1828.9kbits/sframe=41620 fps=377 q=3.0 size=  309554kB time=00:23:07.33 bitrate=1827.9kbits/sframe=41819 fps=377 q=3.0 size=  310873kB time=00:23:13.96 bitrate=1826.9kbits/sframe=42018 fps=378 q=3.0 size=  312242kB time=00:23:20.60 bitrate=1826.3kbits/sframe=42221 fps=378 q=3.0 size=  313435kB time=00:23:27.36 bitrate=1824.4kbits/sPast duration 0.939995 too large
frame=42422 fps=378 q=3.0 size=  314682kB time=00:23:34.06 bitrate=1823.0kbits/sframe=42626 fps=378 q=3.0 size=  315879kB time=00:23:40.86 bitrate=1821.2kbits/sframe=42824 fps=378 q=3.0 size=  317120kB time=00:23:47.46 bitrate=1819.9kbits/sframe=43023 fps=378 q=3.0 size=  318314kB time=00:23:54.10 bitrate=1818.3kbits/sframe=43219 fps=378 q=3.0 size=  319492kB time=00:24:00.63 bitrate=1816.8kbits/sframe=43408 fps=378 q=3.0 size=  320726kB time=00:24:06.93 bitrate=1815.8kbits/sPast duration 0.999992 too large
frame=43606 fps=378 q=3.0 size=  321942kB time=00:24:13.53 bitrate=1814.4kbits/sframe=43794 fps=378 q=3.0 size=  323129kB time=00:24:19.80 bitrate=1813.3kbits/sframe=43991 fps=378 q=3.0 size=  324404kB time=00:24:26.36 bitrate=1812.3kbits/sframe=44193 fps=378 q=3.0 size=  325595kB time=00:24:33.10 bitrate=1810.7kbits/sframe=44392 fps=378 q=3.0 size=  326776kB time=00:24:39.73 bitrate=1809.1kbits/sframe=44595 fps=379 q=3.0 size=  327973kB time=00:24:46.50 bitrate=1807.4kbits/sframe=44787 fps=379 q=3.0 size=  329320kB time=00:24:52.90 bitrate=1807.1kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame=44982 fps=379 q=3.0 size=  330473kB time=00:24:59.40 bitrate=1805.5kbits/sframe=45175 fps=379 q=3.0 size=  331670kB time=00:25:05.83 bitrate=1804.3kbits/sframe=45377 fps=379 q=3.0 size=  333104kB time=00:25:12.56 bitrate=1804.1kbits/s[msmpeg4 @ 0x7fbe51801200] warning, clipping 1 dct coefficients to -127..127
frame=45561 fps=379 q=3.0 size=  334298kB time=00:25:18.70 bitrate=1803.2kbits/sPast duration 0.619987 too large
frame=45748 fps=379 q=3.0 size=  336189kB time=00:25:24.93 bitrate=1806.0kbits/sframe=45926 fps=379 q=3.0 size=  337726kB time=00:25:30.86 bitrate=1807.2kbits/sframe=46104 fps=378 q=3.0 size=  339048kB time=00:25:36.80 bitrate=1807.3kbits/sframe=46236 fps=378 q=3.0 Lsize=  340729kB time=00:25:41.58 bitrate=1810.6kbits/s dup=3 drop=76
video:309568kB audio:24087kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.120339%
```

Comment: Hey vince, welcome to the site! Just to point it out, because it can get people on here very frustrated with you - you never expressly asked a question. You outlined your problem and what you would like as the outcome, but you never actually asked the question "How do I do this" or somesuch. Now, and I am BY NOO MEANS an ffmpeg novice even, but you may have to try and have it pipe the output out of one into another or something similar. I'm sure someone will have a better, much more specific answer though!

Comment: You should show the complete console output from your `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: @PsychoData sorry about that. Added a question.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, there aren't actually any errors in the execution (I foolishly forgot I erased a parameter in the original post, but that's been corrected) so the output file looks fairly standard to me. I'll add the output to the OP though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a method using the [concat filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat):

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -loop 1 -t 5 -framerate 30 -i image.jpg -t 5 -f lavfi -i anullsrc -filter_complex \
"[1:v]scale=640:-1,pad=iw:ih*(4/3):0:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1/1[title]; \
 [title][2:a][0:v][0:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
 -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.wmv
```

- This will letterbox the title instead of the main video. The title will be 5 seconds in duration (see the `-t 5` options).
- Trying to do this using the [concat demuxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat) to avoid re-encoding the main segment is probably not possible because there is no VC-1 video encoder in `ffmpeg` to make the title segment (not that anybody really cares about VC-1).